How can I check if a website is hosted/powered by who they say it is?
I have to purchase some teaching materials and I am planning to utilize this website: https://www.magistrajoneslatin.com/
I was preparing to enter our debit card information when I realized I should probably check to ensure it is hosted by/with a reputable processor. The website says it is hosted using Squarespace, but how do I know if this is true?

You can’t; Anyone can pay the fee to have a SSL/TLS certificate.

You can perform a reverse DNS lookup on the host to see if that helps.  In this case, it does:
https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=www.magistrajoneslatin.com&rtype=ALL&dns=opendns
The output (simplified for your use) includes:
A Records

A www.magistrajoneslatin.com

Owner: Squarespace Inc. [United States of America]
A www.magistrajoneslatin.com

Canonical Name
CNAME www.magistrajoneslatin.com
ext-sq.squarespace.com.

This matches records of other known SquareSpace sites.

This a good answer, and not that this is the point, but just because they are registered with an official company does not in any way remotely guarantee authenticity. Criminals go to many lengths to trick unsuspecting people...
